# How can I improve the performance of this brute force code for finding files with the same hash?

Tags: python, performance, hash, sha1

The code works under the assumption that a lot of time is given. Is there any way or logic to change this code to be a little more efficient?

```
while(1):
    with open('./output_file', 'wb') as fout:
        fout.write(os.urandom(piece_size))

    f = open('./output_file', 'rb')
    data = f.read()
    print(hashlib.sha1(data).hexdigest())
    if (hashlib.sha1(data).hexdigest() == '37fbfdb93e39d41d53270184d050a83a08cb772e'):
        print("same")
        print("file hash : "+hashlib.sha1(data).hexdigest())
        break
```

Comment: Don't call `hashlib.sha1(data)` 3 times. Call it once and assign it to a variable.

Comment: You can't avoid hashing every file, so there isn't really any way to speed it up beyond that.

Comment: But what does `os.urandom()` have to do with finding files with the same hash?

Comment: @Barmar I wanted to write some brute force attack code to find a random byte array with a hash value equal to a given hash value.

Comment: What does this even have to do with files? You're overwriting a specific file over and over again, only to right away read it.

Comment: if you are trying to find a file that matches a specific hash then i don't think there is a way round calculating the hash of every file.

if you are trying to find any two files that have the same hash then you can start by checking files that are the same size, if the file size is different then they will not have the same hash (unless it is a specially crafted file) - https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2583/is-it-fair-to-assume-that-sha1-collisions-wont-occur-on-a-set-of-100k-strings

Comment: In your tests, did the code ever break out of the *while* loop?

Comment: @SomeoneRandom3142
I'm implementing a logic that randomly creates a file with the same hash, rather than 'Searching' it.

Comment: you will never be able to generate two random files with the same hash or a random file that matches a specific hash (not in a single lifetime anyway)  there are ways to force a collision but they require extensive computational resources

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the challenge is to search for a file whose hash (hex digest) matches some constant, then you could do it like this:

```
import glob
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import hashlib

R = []

def checkhash(file, hash):
    try:
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            if hashlib.sha1(f.read()).hexdigest() == hash:
                R.append(file)
    except Exception:
        pass

def check():
    if R:
        print(f'Match found for {R[0]}')
        return True
    return False

def main(hash):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        found = False
        futures = []
        for file in glob.glob('*'): # adjust pattern for location of files to be checked
            futures.append(executor.submit(checkhash, file, hash))
            if (found := check()): # potential early break
                break
        for future in futures: # wait for all running threads to complete
            future.result()
        if not found and not check():
            print('Not found')
                


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('40161156c793cc85322f5774a1225e4413288cba')
```

Comment: Can you explain what the code does?